# C Multithreading without pthreads: "The program no longer exists" Seg fault

Tags: c, multithreading

This is for an assignment where we have to do multithreading without pthreads. The code to be executed in each thread calculates the sum of numbers between 0 and input integer arguments. So far the program works fine when only using a single thread, but when trying to create multiple threads I get a Segmentation fault.

I got some code from a few sources and modified it to get the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//Source for threading outline: http://www.evanjones.ca/software/threading.html

// 64kB stack
#define FIBER_STACK 1024*64

struct sum_runner_struct {
    long long limit;
    long long answer;
};

// The child threads will execute this function
int threadFunction( void* argument )
{
    struct sum_runner_struct *arg_struct = (struct sum_runner_struct*) argument;
    long long sum = 0;
    long long i = 0;
    //Calculate the sum of numbers between 0 and input argument
    for (i; i <= arg_struct->limit; i++) {
        sum+=i;
    }

    arg_struct->answer = sum;
         printf( "child thread exiting\n" );
         return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Wrong number of args\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int num_args = argc - 1;

    struct sum_runner_struct args[num_args];


         void* stack;
     //Thread IDs
         pid_t pids[num_args];

         // Allocate the stack
         stack = malloc( FIBER_STACK );
         if ( stack == 0 )
         {
                 perror( "malloc: could not allocate stack" );
                 exit( 1 );
         }

         printf( "Creating child threads\n" );

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < num_args; i++) {
        args[i].limit = atoll(argv[i + 1]);

            // Call the clone system call to create the child threads
             pids[i] = clone( &threadFunction, (char*) stack + FIBER_STACK,
                 SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, &args[i] );
             if ( pids[i] == -1 )
                 {
                        perror( "clone" );
                        exit( 2 );
             }
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (j; j < num_args; j++) {
            // Wait for the child threads to exit
            pids[j] = waitpid( pids[j], 0, 0 );
        //Prints the answers that were computed in the child threads
        printf("Sum is %lld\n", args[j].answer);
            if ( pids[j] == -1 )
                {
                        perror( "waitpid" );
                        exit( 3 );
                 }
            }
         // Free the stack
         free( stack );

         printf( "Child threads returned and stack freed.\n" );

         return 0;
}
```

Debugging using gdb, the program executes until line 70, when the threads are created:

```
pids[i] = clone( &threadFunction, (char*) stack + FIBER_STACK,
                 SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, &args[i] );
```

Then when I step past it I get this:

```
70               pids[i] = clone( &threadFunction, (char*) stack + FIBER_STACK,
(gdb) s
Detaching after fork from child process 29143.
child thread exiting
Detaching after fork from child process 29144.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

Again, this only happens when trying to create multiple threads. The program works as expected with only a single thread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the same stack to all the threads. Hence the threads will stomp all over each other. And also why it works with one thread.

Comment: Oh stunning!   OP - give up now:)

Comment: First day with threads and still very new at C. Give me a break guys :P

Comment: lol, it's just that the most important attribute of a thread is that it has its own stack!